# Ocaml pattern matching multiple elements in a list at once

Tags: ocaml, design-patterns, element, matching

Lets say I have a list of type integer [1; 2; 3; 4; 5; 6; 7; 8] and I want to pattern match the first three elements at once. Is there any way to do this without nested match statements?

for example, can it be done like this?

```
let rec f (x: int list) : (int list) = 
begin match x with
| [] -> []
| [a; b; c]::rest -> (blah blah blah rest of the code here)
end
```

I could use the long nested method, which would be:

```
let rec f (x: int list) : (int list) =
begin match x with
| [] -> []
| h1::t1 ->
  begin match t1 with
  | [] -> []
  | h2::t2 ->
     begin match t2 with
     | [] -> []
     | t3:: h3 ->
        (rest of the code here)
     end
  end
end
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can do that.  The syntax is like this:

```
let rec f (x: int list) : (int list) = 
begin match x with
| [] -> []
| a::b::c::rest -> (blah blah blah rest of the code here)
end
```

but you'll notice that this will fail if the list has fewer than three elements.  You can either add cases for single and two element lists, or just add a case that matches anything:

```
let rec f (x: int list) : (int list) = 
  match x with
  | a::b::c::rest -> (blah blah blah rest of the code here)
  | _ -> []
```

Comment: cool, thanks! And lets say for the (blah blah blah rest of the code here) I wanted to return everything except element "a." would i just do b@c@rest?

Comment: you can match with, `a::((b::c::rest) as tl)` and then you can use `tl` without recreating the head elements of the list.